# Get child from inherit class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have 2 classes

```
public class A
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a method to fill a List with type `B`.

Question: What is the easiest way to get the result into `List<A>`

```
List<B> BList = new List<B>();
BList = GetData(); //fill List with Data
List<A> AList = (List<A>)BList; // convert? cast?
```

Class `A` has all fields of Class `B` so there must be a easy way to get from `B` to `A`.

Comment: the duplicate link is not about inheritance

Comment: The first answer is.

Comment: Since you have a `List` here, you could also use Linq projection  `List<A> AList = BList.Select(b => (A)b).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Linq function:

```
List<A> AList = BList.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a new `List<A>` instance with references to all the items from `BList`:

```
List<A> AList = new List<A>(BList);
```

That's because `List<T>` is not covariant (and can't be).

Comment: Thank you both for answering.